# Version 12.04 takes forever to boot into kernel 3.2.0-36

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel

As you can see from the title, I am having trouble with booting into the newest kernel of Linux (3.2.0-36) from the grub.  I am dual-booting Windows 7 Pro with Ubuntu 12.04 and running Ubuntu as my primary OS.  I have done a lot of checking in the forums and still haven't found a solution that solves my problem.

My problem is that when I attempt to boot into the default Linux kernel, the boot takes forever and nothing is displayed (except a purplish screen that reminds my of the BSOD).  I am a total noob to Ubuntu so I have no idea what I can and can't do in the boot, such as opening terminals, getting error reports, etc.  I started using the 12.04 just a few weeks ago.  If I do a boot repair (which I had to originally from the LiveCD in order to get the grub to work), I can boot into the newest kernel quickly once and then every subsequent boot takes forever.  Also, I have noticed that there are a few stability issues, such as programs randomly closing (my screencasting software).  However, one last thing to mention, I am able to boot into a previous version of the kernel (I am currently in 3.2.0-26).

Does anybody have any ideas?

P.S.  If you want to see any error reports, you will need to "spell it out" due to my status as a noob, but I do want to learn all that stuff so feel free to slap me upside the head.  :)

Comment: I have boot repaired up and down the ying-yang.  Nothing works.  I even tried reinstalling the grub.  Didn't work.

Comment: If the updated kernel often fails to boot and causes stability problems when it does run, that's probably a bug; I recommend [reporting it as such](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). ([This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) also has some good information about bug reporting.) After reading that (or at least the first linked page), you can start the report by running `ubuntu-bug linux`. This will probably be closed as off-topic, in accordance with [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) and [this policy](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/228/22949).

Comment: Since you have tried [everything here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it), you should make sure to include a detailed explanation of what you tried and what happened, in the bug report. In particular, it's important that the report make clear that boot options like `nomodeset` did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's a kernel regression.

1. **Short-term solution:** remove the 3.2.0-36 kernel from your /boot/grub/grub.cfg file. (use `gksudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg` to edit it), or remove the packages related to 3.2.0-36.
2. Also report the bug to kernel developers, via the `ubuntu-bug linux` command. If you don't, you will have the same bug in future Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for the info.  I was wondering what was causing that.  However, I still have a few problems with the current kernel (unable to shutdown. I forgot to mention that in the original post).  Is there anything, I can do to fix that? Maybe, I will try to re-install???

Comment: You can try the `sudo shutdown now` command. Reinstalling won't change anything.